# Recaptcha blocking because Google insists on "Modern Browsers"

Tags: feature-request, captcha

Shouldn't there be a way to post to Stack Overflow without installing someone's particular version special browser?

I've seen the following happen on other sites, its probably due to code changes by Google.

Now a days, getting a proof of humanity challenge, Google's current reCaptcha code insists on "Modern Browsers"

Which means my non-mainstream browser with NoScript enabled (but allowing google) isn't allowed to complete the challenge.

Up to recently it did captchas fine

It feels like this is a play on Google's part to push adoption of Chrome

I'd expect Stack Overflow to adhere to technical standards, and insisting on particular versions of particular browser's isn't really a technical standard.  Theoretically if someone created a web browser of their own, fully complant to standars for HTML and JS, they should be allowed to post with it to Stack Overflow

Comment: Not the first or last time Google deliberately breaks things in other browsers to push users to use Chrome

Comment: Is the browser you're using [one of the officially supported browsers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)? Browsers outside that range have no guarantees that they'll work.

Comment: It's Fire Fox.  Not the latest release though

Comment: So you are using an outdated, likely insecure, browser on purpose?!

Comment: Is it an indirect attack on the monopoly of google on web technologies and forcing people into developing sites accordingly? Also, @ThiefMaster it shouldn't happen that SE progresses so fast that people with old systems are left out too early.

Comment: there is absolutely no reason to support any Firefox version except for the two latest releases + LTS...

Comment: @ThiefMaster your concept that open-source projects cannot be forked and customized, creating personalized, unique, versions is certainly different than the convectional wisdom of open-source circles

Comment: @infixedit's very uncommon for people to fork something as big as firefox and use this for day-to-day browsing :)

Comment: @Thiefmaster, it is very odd that you think software which incorporates plug-ins and add-ons as part of its design doesn't get changed from original flavor a lot.  Do you wonder why they put in such features?  Do you think everyone wants to use the same things?